# using Ember-data with JSONApi and opening page in a new tab

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I have a page that has pictures (`index.js`) and when you click a picture, a detail page with bigger version of the picture and its content (`pic.js`) opens. When I was using hard-coded data, I created a service and put the data in it. By this way, the model hook wasn't skipped when I click a picture. I did it because my links are dynamic `{{#link-to}}` helper and I saw that model hook gets skipped when you have it. But now, I need to use JSON api to get the data from an URL, when I do it in the `index.js` there is no problem with displaying it but when I try to open any link in new tab or paste a link in URL bar, model hook doesn't work in `pic.js`.

```
//routes/index.js

import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
    model() {
        return Ember.$.getJSON('My jsonApi Url');
    }
});
```

I read that I need to use ember-data in order to fix it. I created a model "news-list" and put attributes in it. Also I created an adapter and take the code which I call API from index.js and put there.

```
//adapters/application.js

import JSONAPIAdapter from 'ember-data/adapters/json-api';
import Ember from 'ember';

export default JSONAPIAdapter.extend({

    model(params){

        return Ember.$.getJSON('My jsonApi Url',params.NewsUrl);

    }
});

//templates/index.hbs

{{image-list model=model.Data currentPos=currentPos }}
{{outlet}}

//templates/components/image-list.hbs

{{#each model as |pic|}}
  <div>{{#link-to "pic" pic}}    
     <p class="info">{{pic.Title}}</p><br/>
     <img src={{pic.Image}} width="300">
  {{/link-to}}</div> {{/each}}
{{yield}}

//routes/pic.js

import Ember from 'ember'; 
export default Ember.Route.extend({ 
activate: function() { 
this._super(...arguments); 
window.scrollTo(0,0); 
}, 
model() { 
//return this.store.findAll('news-list'); 
} 
});

//templates/pic.hbs
<p class= "back">{{#link-to 'index'}}Home Page{{/link-to}}</p>
<p class="detail"><img src="{{model.Image}}" width="600" ></p>
<p class="content"><br/><br/>{{model.Content}}</p><br/><br/>
<p class= "back">{{#link-to 'index'}}Home Page{{/link-to}}</p>

{{outlet}}
```

I tried to use `return this.store.findAll('news-list');` in the `pic.js` but then all I see was a blank page when I click a picture. 
I guess there is something I'm missing. I can't use ember-data properly. How can I fix it?

Comment: Why you are passing model.Data to model in image-list, shouldn't it be model=model?

Comment: ıt's in index.js. I do it because I'm getting data from JsonApi and if f I use model = model, nothing appears in the main page. I can only get model's data. What do you think about the other problem?

Comment: Try with #link-to 'pic' pic.id instead of pic

Comment: Nope, now model hook doesn't work even if I directly click to a link.

Comment: Can you post pic.js route?

Comment: `import Ember from 'ember';
export default Ember.Route.extend({
    activate: function() {
        this._super(...arguments);
        window.scrollTo(0,0);
    },
    model() {
            //return this.store.findAll('news-list');
}
});`

Comment: can you edit the original post to have `routes/pics.js`? it's tough to read code in a comment.

Comment: also, what is the endpoint to get just one pic from your api?

Comment: Ok I edited the post, added both pic.js and pic.hbs. I don't understand your question, JSON api is not something I'm so familiar with. I directly take the link, I don't get only one pic.

Comment: Can you try placing activate() below model() in pic.js?

Comment: I tried, still the same :/ works when I left click, doesn't work when I open in a new tab.

Comment: Does that "application.js" (adapter) do anything at all? It seems so useless to me. Like, is it even connected to something? I think the same with the model "news-list.js".Maybe I can't use them properly?

Comment: This is close to what you need to do: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/jevimehuru/1/edit?html,js,output .  Even though ember data is used in this example, ember data is not necessary for your implementation.